# Android debugging ndk : permission denied

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, gdb, permission-denied

I am developing a 3D App as a native C++ program.

Doing on Eclipse IDE:

```
* Started the Android application
* launched GDB server on the device
* launched GDB client

Error starting process.
Cannot run program 
/app3D/obj/local/armeabi/app_process
: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
```

Then, I have changed the permission:

```
chmod -R 777 /opt/android/android-ndk-r7
chmod -R 777 /home/project/app3D
```

But the same error persist.

Has someone experienced a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the build_binary.mk at \android-ndk\build\core\build-binary.mk got rid of this error:

```
#    $(hide) $(call cmd-strip, $(PRIVATE_DST))
ifneq ($(APP_OPTIM),debug)
    $(hide) $(call cmd-strip, $(PRIVATE_DST))
endif
```

And also added to command the following paramenter:

```
ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

That's weird, the executable is normally located in the libs/armeabi folder, not the obj folder...